# Magento 2 Show special prices start and end dates

Tags: magento2, special-price, custom-theme, theme-overriding

I have added a product with special price, Template is already showing special price with original price strike through over it

[image]

I want to show special price start and end dates beneath product price, how to achieve this

I have tried this with custom theme to override price in `My/CustomTheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` in a hope it will show my template underneath `product.info.price` of the original applied theme

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
      <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.price.special.dates" after="product.info.price" template="special.phtml">
    </referenceContainer>
  </body>
</page>
```

and will show dates in `special.phtml`

Comment: Use these function: $product->getSpecialFromDate()  //Start date  
$product->getSpecialToDate()  // End Date

Comment: where should I do this is the question

Comment: In special.phtml file

Answer (score 0):

I did this by creating a module rather,

with view file //view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.price">
      <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\SpecialPrice" name="special_price_dates" after="product.price.final"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="special_price_dates">
      <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">special_price.phtml</argument>
      </action>
    </referenceBlock>
  </body>
</page>
```